# Can conditional probability P(B|A) > P(B)?

Tags: probability

For any two events A and B with both P(A) and P(B) > 0, is it possible that the conditional probability P(B|A) can be greater than P(B)? If yes, how so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For instance, if $A\subset B$ and $\mathbb{P}(B)<1$, then
$$ \mathbb{P}(B\mid A)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}=1>\mathbb{P}(B)$$

Comment: what if $P(A\cap B)=0$?

Comment: @Piyush Divyanakar: If $A\subset B$ and $\mathbb{P}(A)>0$ then $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A)>0$.

Comment: Let B be the event that 2 coin tosses result in HH, and A be the event that first toss is T. P(B)=0.25, P(A)=0.5 and P(B|A)=0. In this case this inequality doesn't hold.

Comment: @Piyush Divyanakar: In your example, it is not the case that $A\subset B$.

Comment: @Piyush Divyanakar: Perhaps you are misunderstanding the question. The OP is not asking whether $\mathbb{P}(B\mid A)>\mathbb{P}(B)$ *always* holds, but whether it can hold for some choice of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Oh i got confused. Nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, informally if $B$ is rare but $A$ is associated strongly with $B$, so that given $A$, $B$ is very likely.

Example: it might be rare for your car to break down, but given the warning light is on, it's much more likely...

(Note that probability says nothing about cause-and-effect)